# While converting feature class to spatially enabled dataframe shape_length data is not populating

Tags: arcgis-python-api, hosted-feature-layer

I am converting feature class to spatially enabled data frame using below code, after conversion shape_length field of a line layer is not getting populated. Only shape data is available. Why this is happening while conversion ?

```
fc = os.path.join(geodatabase_path, layer_name)
sedf = arcgis.GeoAccessor.from_featureclass(fc)
```

Comment: length is a property of the geometry